# I am making a quiz-like program. I already wrote the string answer ="George Washington". but when the user inputted the answer, it's wrong

Tags: c++

```
answer = "George";      
cout << "\t\t\t\t\t Who was the first President of United States?" << endl;
cout << "";
cout << "";
cout << "Congrats " << player1_name << " (Player1). Now, type in your answer:";
cin >> player1_answer;
                
if (player1_answer == answer){
cout << "check";
}else{
cout << "x";
}
```

This is my code. But when the user inputted the answer as exactly as what was written in the answer variable, it outputs 'x'. But if the user inputted the same answer excluding the space between "George" and "Washington", it outputs 'check'. What should I do so that the program will accept the space in the answer inputted by the user?

I tried searching the web but I can't understand a thing. So please help me

Comment: When asking a code related question, the very first tag you should add is for the language you're using. Also, your code says the correct answer is "George", not "George Washington". (And why are you congratulating the player **before** they input their answer? Are you congratulating them for reading "Who was the first President?"?)

Comment: This question's shown code fails to meet Stackoverflow's requirements for showing a [mre]. Because of that it's unlikely that anyone here can conclusively answer the question; but only guess at the most. You need to [edit] your question to show a minimal example, no more than one or two pages of code (the "minimal" part), that everyone else can cut/paste ***exactly as shown***, compile, run, and reproduce the described issue (the "reproducible" part, this includes any ancillary information, like any input to the program). See [ask] for more information.

Comment: Please make your code match your question. (There is no mention of "Washington" in your code, despite its prominence in your question.)

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use [`getline`](https://cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/) instead of `cin`. `cin` reads the user input up until the first whitespace character (most commonly newlines or spaces), but `getline` will read user input until they hit enter. Because of this, if you want to get user input that includes spaces, you should use `getline` (or something similar) instead of `cin`.

Instead of

```cpp
cin >> player1_answer;
```

you should use

```cpp
getline(cin, player1_answer);
```

By using getline, the full user input ("George Washington") get assigned to the variable `player1_answer`. With `cin`, only "George" was being used, because it stopped listening for input after the first space.

Here is a full, working code example:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
string answer = "George Washington";
string player1_name = "Steve";
string player1_answer;
cout << "\t\t\t\t\t Who was the first President of United States?" << endl;
cout << "";
cout << "";
cout << "Congrats " << player1_name << " (Player1). Now, type in your answer:";
getline(cin, player1_answer); //Enter "George Washington"

if (player1_answer == answer){
    cout << "check";
}else{
    cout << "x";
}
//"check"
return -1;
```